# Services do not appear in sc list

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, service

We have a couple of application services that are registered and appear in the MMC Service list, but when I use the sc command they do not appear.

```
sc query type= all
```

Are there restrictions on what services appear in this list? I intend to add a Dependency if the tool will allow me. Or will I have to follow [this serverfault article](https://serverfault.com/questions/84181/can-the-startup-order-for-windows-services-be-configured-if-so-where) advice?